# How to optimize my VBA code to work with an 11,000-data database

Tags: excel, vba, database, optimization, query-optimization

My code goes through my database (list of all the consumables that have left our warehouse in the last 5 years) and adds a consumable on a second sheet each time it encounters a new consumable which has not already been compiled in the second sheet.

It copies the number of the new consumable as well as 4 other columns describing it in the second sheet. Then, for each data compiled in the second sheet, it goes through the database of the first sheet and checks the sectors of activity in which this consumable has been used. The code therefore makes an X in the cyanidation column for each consumable that has been used in this sector and the same for the flotation column.

```vb
Sub CopierColler()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
    Application.EnableEvents = False    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")    
    Set Ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil2")
    
    k = 1
    
    While Ws1.Range("G" & k).Value <> ""    
        k = k + 1    
    Wend
    
    For i = 1 To k    
        h = 1    
        While Ws2.Range("A" & h).Value <> ""
            h = h + 1
        Wend
        j = 1
        While j < h
            If Ws1.Range("G" & i).Value <> Ws2.Range("A" & j).Value Then
            j = j + 1
            Else: j = h + 2
            End If
        Wend
        If j = h Then
        Ws1.Range("G1:K1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Copy Ws2.Range("A1:E1").Offset(h - 1, 0)
        End If
    Next
    
    k = 1
    
    While Ws2.Range("A" & k).Value <> ""    
        k = k + 1    
    Wend
    
    For i = 1 To k    
        h = 1    
        While Ws1.Range("G" & h).Value <> ""
            h = h + 1
        Wend
        j = 1
        While j < h
            If Ws1.Range("G" & j).Value = Ws2.Range("A" & i).Value And Ws1.Range("G" & j).Offset(0, -2).Value = "Flottation" _
            And Ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 5).Value = "" Then
            Ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 5).Value = "X"
            End If
            If Ws1.Range("G" & j).Value = Ws2.Range("A" & i).Value And Ws1.Range("G" & j).Offset(0, -2).Value = "Cyanuration" _
            And Ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 6).Value = "" Then
            Ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 6).Value = "X"
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Wend
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
    Application.EnableEvents = True    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub
```

Explanation of code:

I found the first and last lines on the internet when I was trying to lighten my code.

Then I start by doing a « while » loop to find the line number (k) corresponding tothe last row of my data sheet (Ws1).

Then I did a « for » loop that will go through each of the rows of my data sheet (Ws1) until the last (k) . In my « For » loop I did a « While » loop to find the line number (h) corresponding to the last row of my second sheet (Ws2). Then I made another « While » loop which continues as long as my counter j is not = the number of rows (h) of my sheet 2 (Ws2), so for each of the data of my sheet Ws1, I compare them with each data from my Ws2 sheet and if I find that the data from the Ws1 sheet is already in the Ws2 sheet then I exit the « While » loop (h+2) and I go to the next data (i) from my Ws1 sheet (for loop) . However, if the Ws1 data is not in the Ws2 sheet then j=h and I copy the data and its descriptive columns into my sheet 2 (Ws2).

Then I use the same principle and take each of the data from my Ws2 and search through all the data from the Ws1. With an “If” I find each of the same data and I look in their “sector” column in the Ws1 and if it is written flotation and if an “X” is not yet noted in the flotation column of the Ws2 I add a « X » in the column. I do the same for the Cyanuration sector. (A consumable can be used only in flotation or in cyanidation but also for both.)

Here is my database reduced to 60 data:

[image]

Here is an example of the result of the code on a database of 60 data:

[image]

| DATE | Mois | N° Centre de Coûts | Sous-Activité | Secteur | Description De Site | Article | Désignation | Unité | Catégorie | Groupe | Description de Compte | Quantité | P.M.P | Montant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-130 | Déblayage - Production ST | Production | SCOOPS 3T N°1 | RP007.3120 | PNEU X-MINE D2 TL 12.00 R24 | UN | Fournitures et Consommables | Fournitures d'Entretien | Pneus et Réparation de Pneus | 2 | 17 000 | 34 000 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 426-280 | Gestion du Parc à Résidus |  | DIGUE N° 1 DE L'USINE FLOTTATION | WL011.9015 | POMPE A ARBRE NUE MARQUE SEPMA TYPE ARS 65-4 | UN | Pièces et Équipement | Autres Composants d'Équipement | Pompes | 1 | 21 080 | 21 080 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-120 | Abattage - Production ST | Production | ABATTAGE | NA001.3250 | CARTOUCHE TOVEX S2 DIA.30/250 | KG | Fournitures et Consommables | Explosifs | Explosif (Émulsion) | 305 | 31 | 9 564 |
| 2022-06-15 | 6 | 422-210 |  | Flottation | CONCASSAGE A MACHOIRE PRIMIAIRE FL | AT002.4210 | TOLE CREUSABRO 2000X1000X10 QUALITE 8000 | UN | Fournitures et Consommables | Fournitures d'Entretien | Plaques et Poutres d'Acier | 7 | 4 320 | 30 240 |
| 2022-02-04 | 2 | 422-230 | Flottation | Flottation | FLOTTATION | LC002.1122 | AMMONIUM DIBUTYL DITHIOPHOSPHATE | KG | Fournitures et Consommables | Produits Chimiques et Réactifs | Ammonium Dibutyl | 1 200 | 21 | 25 349 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2204 | Développment Minier |  | CESSIONS SOCIETE TRAGI | NA002.0001 | AMORCE RETARD LONGUEUR FIL 2.5m | UN | Fournitures et Consommables | Explosifs | Accessoire de Dynamitage | 327 | 19 | 6 257 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 424-245 | Cementation et Fusion |  | FONDERIE DE FUSION | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 600 | 8 | 4 997 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 110-101 | Exploration - Zgounder |  | GROUPE ELECTROGENE 500KVA N°1 | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 400 | 8 | 3 332 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1002 | Bassin de rétention d'eau |  | CAMION DE LOCATION 8*4 (1827-A-74) | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 204 | 8 | 1 699 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-110 | Forage - Production ST | Production | COMPRESSEUR MOBILE N°2 (FOND) REF : 102 | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 200 | 8 | 1 666 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1002 | Bassin de rétention d'eau |  | POCLIN DE LOCATION | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 200 | 8 | 1 666 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1002 | Bassin de rétention d'eau |  | POCLIN DE LOCATION | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 200 | 8 | 1 666 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1002 | Bassin de rétention d'eau |  | POCLIN DE LOCATION | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 200 | 8 | 1 666 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1002 | Bassin de rétention d'eau |  | COMPACTEUR LOCATION | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 200 | 8 | 1 666 |
| 2022-06-30 | 6 | 422-230 |  | Flottation | FLOTTATION | LC002.1122 | AMMONIUM DIBUTYL DITHIOPHOSPHATE | KG | Fournitures et Consommables | Produits Chimiques et Réactifs | Ammonium Dibutyl | 1 065 | 21 | 22 497 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 422-260 | Opérations Concentrateur | Flottation | SUPERVISION USINE FLOTTATION | KT007.3420 | COURROIE TRAPEZOIDALE C135 SECTION 22x3420 | UN | Pièces et Équipement | Revêtements et pièces d'usure | Courroies | 8 | 185 | 1 480 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 426-280 | Gestion du Parc à Résidus |  | CHARGEUSE SUR PNEUS 950H | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 171 | 8 | 1 424 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-140 | Roulage - Production ST | Production | DUMPER N°4 | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 167 | 8 | 1 391 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 422-260 | Opérations Concentrateur | Flottation | SUPERVISION USINE FLOTTATION | KT007.2946 | COURROIE TRAPEZOIDALE C116 SECTION 22x2946 | UN | Pièces et Équipement | Revêtements et pièces d'usure | Courroies | 6 | 200 | 1 200 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 422-230 | Flottation | Flottation | FLOTTATION | TV060.6100 | VANNEA OPERCULE A BRIDE DE 4" | UN | Pièces et Équipement | Autres Composants d'Équipement | Tuyaux et Raccords de Tuyauterie | 1 | 1 063 | 1 063 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 422-240 | Épaississeur et Filtration | Flottation | FILTRATION FL | EC001.6706 | CONTACTEUR REF.LC1D8011M5 R/P REF.LC1D80M5 TELEMECANIQUE | UN | Pièces et Équipement | Pièces Électriques | Pièces de Rechange Électrique | 1 | 980 | 980 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 422-230 | Flottation | Flottation | FLOTTATION | TT801.0004 | VANNE OCA PN16 DN 100 | UN | Pièces et Équipement | Autres Composants d'Équipement | Tuyaux et Raccords de Tuyauterie | 1 | 940 | 940 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-130 | Déblayage - Production ST | Production | SCOOPS 3T N°1 | RP012.2120 | CHAMBRE A AIR 1200X24 | UN | Fournitures et Consommables | Fournitures d'Entretien | Pneus et Réparation de Pneus | 2 | 420 | 840 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-130 | Déblayage - Production ST | Production | SCOOPS 6T N°5 | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 100 | 8 | 833 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-130 | Déblayage - Production ST | Production | SCOOPS TORO 10T | NG001.0001 | GASOIL 50/10 PPM | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Diesel | 100 | 8 | 833 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-130 | Déblayage - Production ST | Production | SCOOPS 6T N°5 | NH002.0168 | HUILE HYDROLIQUE AW 68 | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Huile a Moteur | 35 | 24 | 830 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-140 | Roulage - Production ST | Production | DUMPER N°3 | XD002.0008 | POCHETTE DE JOINT POUR CYLINDRE REF.213010021 P/DUMPER-8 | UN | Pièces et Équipement | Revêtements et pièces d'usure | Pièces d'Usure | 1 | 782 | 782 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-140 | Roulage - Production ST | Production | DUMPER N°4 | NH002.0168 | HUILE HYDROLIQUE AW 68 | L | Fournitures et Consommables | Carburant et Lubrification | Huile a Moteur | 30 | 24 | 711 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 220-130 | Déblayage - Production ST | Production | SCOOPS 3T N°1 | XS001.0074 | RETENUE REF.203040334 P/CHARGEUSE TRANSPORTEUSE SCOOP-1.5 | UN | Pièces et Équipement | Revêtements et pièces d'usure | Pièces d'Usure | 1 | 711 | 711 |

Comment: I tried my code on 60 data database and everything worked but when I finally put it on my database of 11,000 data it took too long to load

Comment: This question is a way too broad as you didn't even explain what the code should do. First you have nested loops that costs **a lot** of time. Second you have many loops, and that costs more time. So with each database entry the time you need probably grows exponential. • Another thing is you directly access the cells. If you read eveything into arrays, process the arrays and then write them back it is much faster.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Sorry It's my first time using this website and I juste learn VBA, I added more detail!

Comment: @CatherineDesmeules Could you add a small data input and expected output?

Comment: Please keep in mind that we have no idea how your data looks like. Please read [mcve] give some example input data and explain what the code does to get to the output. Screenshots might help to show a consisent set of example data so we can understand what your code does.

Comment: Okok I aded pictures and a description of my code!! @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Please show a _subset_ of your data - and also show your source data as text which can be copy/pasted. Take a look at this [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) - it is easier to help you if one can copy the sample data instead of typing them.

Comment: Ok I did it I put 46 data but I have 10 658 data to treat. @Ike

Comment: Looping down a column cell-by-cell to check for a value is slow - instead you can use something like `Application.Match(valueToFind, ColumnToSearch, 0)` which will be much faster.

Comment: Are the values in Ws2 ColA unique, or can they repeat?

Comment: @TimWilliams No thats the goal! They repeat in Ws1 but I want unique values in Ws2

Comment: In that case the code below should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming values in Ws2 ColA unique, this should be much faster:

```vb
Sub CopierColler()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, Ws1 As Worksheet, Ws2 As Worksheet, c As Range, rngIds As Range
    Dim eVal, id, m
    
    SpeedUp
    
    Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
    Set Ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil2")
    
    'loop over id's in Ws1:G
    For Each c In Ws1.Range("G2:G" & Ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        
        id = c.Value
        If Len(id) > 0 Then
            
            'any match for id in ColA of ws2 ?
            m = Application.Match(id, Ws2.Columns("A"), 0)
            If IsError(m) Then  ' `m` will be an error value if no match was made
                m = Ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row 'next empty cell in ColA
                c.Resize(1, 5).Copy Ws2.Cells(m, "A")                  'copy 5 columns over to Ws2
            End If
            
            eVal = c.EntireRow.Columns("E").Value
            If eVal = "Flottation" Or eVal = "Cyanuration" Then
                'the cell to update (row = m, col = G or H)
                With Ws2.Cells(m, IIf(eVal = "Flottation", "G", "H"))
                    If Len(.Value) = 0 Then .Value = "X"
                End With
            End If
        
        End If 'have an id
    Next c
    
    SpeedUp False 'pass False to turn off speed optimizations
    
End Sub

'Enable/disable settings to optimize worksheet updates
' `SpeedUp` or `SpeedUp True` to enable, `SpeedUp False` to turn off
Sub SpeedUp(Optional turnOn As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not turnOn
    Application.EnableEvents = Not turnOn
    Application.Calculation = IIf(turnOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
End Sub
```